# SSRS Deleted Reports Miraculously came back

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have a strange situation at a client site, and I wonder if anyone's seen this happen and can shed some light.

A bunch of SSRS reports disappeared.

Reporting Server logs actually showed a DeleteItemAction entry, but it was done by the service account that runs SSRS, so there was no one we could go and ask "did you delete".

Users discovered the missing reports the next morning, and we could see repeated attempts to access them.  The strange bit is:

- Some attempts ended in Permission Denied - that was a surprise, but could have simply been people trying different accounts because they couldn't see the report on their usual account
- Most attempts ended in Report not found - it's more what we expected to see, and seemed to support that the reports really weren't there anymore

Then mid-day, the log showed that Reporting services was shutting down, then starting up.  Shortly after that we see users accessing the reports successfully. All is well now, but we are left with a mystery as to what happened.  Was there malicious action, or could this somehow have happened spontaneously.

We were unable to find any events indicating that the reports were being restored, created, recreated, etc. between when they were gone and when they were suddenly back.

How could this happen?

Comment: Query the `Catalog` table in the ReportServer database to see when the reports in question were created (`CreationDate`). Likely their created dates are before the mysterious event and you've encountered a bug that you need to take to Microsoft Support to get resolved.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion!  I've asked the client to give it a try.